# How often are link-local IPv6 addresses renewed by Windows 10? Do they contain any "network prefix"?

Tags: windows-10, ipv6, privacy

- How often are IPv6 addresses renewed by Windows 10?
  I am talking about link local addresses; not temporary random addresses.
- Should it, and does it contain a network ID prefix, which is used by temporary addresses for routing?
  (sorry, I cannot check this at the moment by comparison, because I did not finish configuration yet)
- Is it possible to regularly completely obfuscate the local link IPv6 ?

//The consideration behind this question is how realistic would it be to track down a particular machine days and months after its interface configuration was leaked out (by any means: sneak peek, mistake, or malware)? I consider IPv6 to be a treacherous footprint along with other hardware serial numbers.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 link-local addresses are generated by taking the IPv6 link-local prefix `fe80::` and appending a slightly swizzled version of the interface's MAC address to it. The swizzling involves setting the "locally administered" bit, which is the 2's place bit of the first octet of the MAC address, and putting "fffe" in the middle of the MAC address.

So if your interface's MAC address is 00:11:22:33:44:55, your IPv6 link-local address on that interface will be:

fe80::211:22ff:fe33:4455.

This address only changes if you change your MAC address. But also, this address should never make it off your local network segment. So it can't be used to, say, track your activity between websites, but it could be used by, say, public Wi-Fi hotspot networks to track how often you visit their coffee shops.

Windows 10, like most modern mobile OSes, has the ability to randomize the MAC addresses of interfaces (particularly Wi-Fi), so keep you from being tracked by your Wi-Fi MAC address. That feature would also protect you from being tracked by your IPv6 link-local addresses.

The `fe80::` IPv6 link-local prefix is always used for link-local no matter what IPv6 network you're on, so the use of that prefix is not an information leak.

Comment: >a slightly swizzled version of the interface's MAC address to it.


AFAIK, it is only EUI-64 compliant scheme, which is avoided in client OSes including Windows. So the privacy setting is turned on by default in Windows 7...10. But I am talking about network address prefix which should follow immediately after IP type modifier (fe80...).
IP6s in LAN are self configured depending on that prefix. And I am not sure, is it changed, or it is hardwired to router's MAC? Then, if there is no router, what code would be used in one-rank networks?

Comment: I should also add that Windows 10 randomizes dynamically the exposed "temporary" IP only. The local-link IP stays unchanged for an unstated period of time. During the OS uptime at least. It can be exposed effortlessly by a misconfigured client software, malware, or simply by sneak-peeking (ipconfig /all is not restricted to user accounts in Windows).  So, the question is the same, how often is it renewed? And does it really use the network prefix, or the network prefix is attached only to legally exposed "temporary IPs"?